# LINQ lambda to split a recordset on unknown key

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I think that this question has to exist on SO, I just don't know how to properly express it. I have a data set like

```
TYPE - AMOUNT

Type1 - Amount

Type1 - Amount

Type1 - Amount

Type2 - Amount

Type2 - Amount

Type3 - Amount

Type3 - Amount
```

How can I have a LINQ lambda expression to create X number of lists based on the distinct types? I will not know how many types there are ahead of time. I just need to make sure that each resulting collection is broken down by Type. So the above set, would result in three lists, first one with 3 rows, next with 2 rows, etc, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called grouping:

```
var results = source.GroupBy(x => x.Type)
                    .Select(g => g.ToList())
                    .ToList();
```

It will return `List<List<YourType>>`. You can skip `ToList()` calls to get `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<YourType>>` instead.

Comment: It will result in a List of Lists. Brilliant! thank you